# Avoiding redirection to the Dashboard in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication, dashboard

I understand that I can use the following code in WordPress to ensure that users who are already logged into my site are not re-directed to the Dashboard when they click the login button on my home page:

```
<?php
   if(is_user_logged_in()){
      // redirect to desired page
   }
?>
```

I would be grateful for advice on where I should place this code and which part of it exactly should be overwritten with the URL for the page to which I wish to send logged in users.  I should add that the desired page is the same page as I direct users to on logging in.

Many thanks in advance for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As I undestood about your question, you are trying to prevent users to visualize the dashboard of WordPress. You can prevent non-admin users to go to the Dashboard on the admin init hook.

```
add_action( "admin_init", "prevent_dashboard_non_admin" );
function prevent_dashboard_non_admin() {
  if ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // You can change that home_url() to any page URL you are tring to redirect
  }
}
```

You can put this code inside **functions.php**

Note: This code has not been tested, please leave a comment and I will create the update if you have any issues with it.

**UPDATE**

```
function my_is_loggin_page() {
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' ) {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_redirect( "yourpage" );
        }
    }
}

add_action( "init", "my_is_loggin_page", 12 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this kind suggestion, Alejandro. However, *no* category of user should be directed to the dashboard after logging in.  Currently, users are redirected to my chosen page on logging in via a login button on my home page that links to the login page. If they are already logged in and wish to open a new tab for the home page, clicking on the login-button on the home page causes them to bypass the login page and go straight to the dashboard. Instead, they should go straight to the page they would be directed to if they had logged in for the first time.

Comment: I made an update on my code; I think that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look here, for more perspective: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

If you want to land your Users, for example to this page **example.com/some-page/** after login, you can use this code:

```
function mysite_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
    if (!isset($_GET['loggedout'])) {    
    return (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) ? admin_url() : site_url('/some-page/');   
}    
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'mysite_login_redirect', 10, 3);
```

The algorithm for doing this is simple:

If the user is an administrator, continue to `admin_url()`
Otherwise, redirect to, say the `site_url('/some-page/')`
The `login_redirect` filter will pass three arguments to the function:

- `$redirect_to`
- `$request`
- `$user`

We’re primarily concerned with the third as we can take a look at its roles attribute to determine if it contains the administrator value.

And with that, we are now redirecting non-admin users to the specific page rather then the dashboard.

`site_url('/some-page/')` will transform to **example.com/some-page/**

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I am having *no* difficulties in redirecting admin or non-admin users to my intended landing page on logging in.  The difficulty occurs when individuals who are logged in open up a second copy of the site via an extra browser tab. If they are already logged in via the first browser tab, when they click on the login button using the second tab (which they need to do), they are automatically redirected to the dashboard. I wish them to be redirected to the above landing page. ***This applies both to admin and non-admin users**. The solutions offered so far are for a different type of query.